# Subsetting by number of levels of a variable

Tags: r

I'd like to make a subset of my original dataset, that includes all columns that have not more than `k` levels.

For dataset `x`, assuming `k` is 120:

```
str(x):
$ A            : Factor w/ 1096193 levels ...
$ B            : Factor w/ 3 levels ...
$ C            : Factor w/ 109 levels  ...
```

Should be:

```
str(X'):
$ B             : Factor w/ 3 levels ...
$ C             : Factor w/ 109 levels  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the number of levels for each column with `nlevels`.  Create a logical vector with that (`<= n` - where n is the threshold we seek) and select the columns based on that

```
n <- 120
x[sapply(x, nlevels) <= n]
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
  select_if(~ nlevels(.) <= n))
```